What does "fell on consumption" mean?
I found the next expression "fell on consumption" in the next paragraph:

In the early nineteenth century, the number of British bondholders may have been fewer than 250,000, barely 2 percent of the population. Yet their wealth was more than double the entire national income of the United Kingdom; their income in the region of 7 percent of national income. In 1822 this income – the interest on the national debt – amounted to roughly half of total public spending, yet more than two-thirds of tax revenue was indirect and hence fell on consumption. Even as late as 1870 these proportions were still, respectively, a third and more than half. It would be quite hard to devise a more regressive fiscal system,......

Ferguson, Niall. The Ascent of Money: A Financial History of the World: 10th Anniversary Edition (English Edition) (p. 92). Penguin Publishing Group. Edición de Kindle.
I looked this expression up in Merriam-Webster's Advanced Learner's English Dictionary and I found 2 different senses that might fit into this context which are:
8 : to belong in a particular category or range ▪ This word falls within the class of verbs. ▪ Her political views fall somewhere between liberal and conservative. ▪ His creative output falls into three distinct categories.
9 b — used when something passes to a different and usually a less active or less desirable state or condition ▪ The crowd fell silent. ▪ This word has fallen [=gone] out of use. = This word has fallen into disuse. [=this word is no longer used] ▪ His theories have now fallen into disrepute/disfavor. ▪ The machinery has fallen into disrepair.
My best guess is that consumers end up paying this kind of tax as he criticizes the British regressive taxation system during the 19th century.

Collins Dictionary example sentences for burden falls on [those who have to bear it].

affected consumption

Short version:  "two-thirds of tax came from sales tax"

I. Meaning of "fell on consumption":
In this context, "fell on consumption" means that a significant part of the tax revenue came from taxes on goods and services that people purchased, rather than from direct taxes on income or wealth. Indirect taxes are often included in the price of goods, making them "consumption taxes" that everyone pays when buying items, regardless of income level.
Sense 8 (from Merriam-Webster's dictionary) is suitable here because the phrase describes the tax burden as being categorized as consumption-based, meaning the taxes were placed on goods and services.
II. Understanding the paragraph:
The paragraph on the UK's fiscal policy in the nineteenth century (1800 to 1899) ends with:
"It would be quite hard to devise a more regressive fiscal system."
The author, Niall Ferguson, is highlighting a regressive tax system in 19th-century Britain, where the tax burden largely "fell on consumption."
Since indirect taxes were applied to goods and services, they disproportionately affected lower-income individuals, who spent a larger portion of their income on basic needs.
Meanwhile, the revenue from these taxes went toward paying interest on the national debt, benefiting wealthy bondholders who received this interest.
Effectively, the system transferred resources from ordinary consumers (many of whom were poorer) to wealthy bondholders, which could be seen as "taking from the poor to pay the rich."
This is part of Ferguson's description of the fiscal structure of the time.

I don't have the M-W learners, but I think it's roughly in the sense of:

a. To be given by assignment or distribution: The greatest task fell to me.
-- TheFreeDictionary

It isn't that the tax is changing (9b, "fell silent"/"fell out of use") or that it was classified under the category of "consumption" (8). It's that, like you said, consumer spending was allocated the bulk of the tax burden.
It's a bit uncommon to say it "fell on [abstract noun]" rather than a person, but it happens. You might rephrase it as:

...yet more than two-thirds of tax revenue was indirect, and hence the tax burden fell on consumers.


It's not exactly the responsibility "falling on consumption" - more like the burden falls on [spending rather than earning]. As in The tax burden falls on the poor.

@FumbleFingers Yeah, I guess "responsibility" and "burden" seem closely related in this sense. (the responsibility of paying for something is a burden) I just went for the first dictionary definition that seemed in-the-right-ballpark. If you've got a closer definition I can cite, let me know and I'll change it

The best I can find is this from thefreedictionary -  fall on (or upon) 1. To attack suddenly and viciously: Snipers and irregulars fell on the hapless patrol. 2. To meet with; encounter: a stockbroker who fell on hard times. Where obviously it makes no sense to say the responsibility for experiencing hard times fell on the hapless stockbroker. I don't know why none of the dictionaries explicitly define the "unwanted burden" sense, since most of them do give at least one example of such use.

@FumbleFingers From that link, I like 13.a) "To be given by assignment or distribution: The greatest task fell to me." Consumption spending (as a part of the economy) was allocated the bulk of the tax burden. Does that seem right to you as well? Thanks for the link, it has a really exhaustive listing.

like I said, the exact sense of the cited use is the tax burden falls on consumption. Consumption bears the tax burden.

A paraphrase would be "purchases of goods and services (i.e. consumption) were taxed".
The tax "fell" on such purchases.
The verb fall has  related uses that you might find more familiar.
Consider:

The accent falls on the second syllable.

The second syllable receives the "weight" of the accent.

The decision fell upon the next of kin.

The next of kin had the burden or onus of making the decision.
Those who consumed bore the burden of the tax. But to say that it "fell upon consumption", stating the situation in abstract economics terms, has the consumer lurking in the wings.

There are two kinds of taxes - direct and indirect.
Direct taxes are placed on you at source, such as tax on your income or your property.
Indirect taxes are placed not on individuals, but on purchases, such as sales tax (or 'value added tax' in the UK) or customs charges. They are not direct because if you don't spend money, you don't pay them.
And that's what consumption means - when you consume, or spend money. So, when your text says "yet more than two-thirds of tax revenue was indirect and hence fell on consumption", it means that the indirect tax relied on consumption - it relied on people spending being consumers.

I think M-W 9b is the closest meaning. I interpret your quote as saying indirect tax revenue fell (reduced) as consumption (of what, goods in general?) reduced. In other words, as people bought less (of something) the tax revenue went down. It was this tax revenue that paid for the interest on the national debit, the government bonds owned by the bondholders.

Reasonable interpretation of the sentence in isolation, but I don't think the context supports it.
